# .Net MicroFramework with Custom ARM board

Tags: arm, .net-micro-framework

Is it possible that I use .Net Micro Framework with a custom ARM9 or ARM7 board, and without any display device or input device?
I want to buy a ARM9 IC and make my own board to just controlling a servo motor (for example) without anything else...
Is it possible to program it with .Net Micro Framework? and control output port manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create a custom board with an ARM9 or ARM7 microcontroller and use the .NET Micro Framework. I suggest choosing an exact model match to a supported MicroController. If you don't get an exact match you may need to use the MicroFramework Porting kit and write drivers or modify code in C (not C#) to support any differences.

For example your task is fairly straight forward so I suggest starting at http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/184 Find a board that supports what you need then make your own board based on one of these chips, then just use the available firmware which is generally available for free (confirm before getting too far).

Really unless you are planning to manufacture 100 of your idea, I would consider buying a board for $30 to $65. A quick glance at [www.mouser.com](http://www.mouser.com) showed the Netduino MicroController to be $20 in single unit quantities.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean that the boards which support .Net MicroFramework, are raw boards without any precompiled program on them? I thought these boards have .Net MicroFramework on themselves to have the ability of running .Net programs!! Is this false?

Comment: The firmware is the .NET Micro Framework. The boards listed on Sparkfun have the needed firmware pre-installed. ex. Netduino: The Microcontroller part has 512K of Program Space available, once the .NET Micro Framework is installed the Program Space drops down to 128K.